# Как сделать три зависимых селекта?

Tags: jquery, ооп, php

Добрый день. Подскажите, как сделать три зависимых селекта. Кто знает хороший мануал или готовое решение, подскажите. Желательно вариант, который проверен на MVC.

Comment: поясните что именно вы хотите ? например покажите какой нибудь код где это вам может понадобиться.

Comment: Кода очень много если его выкладывать будет простыня. проблема в том что почемуто не работает Js когда страница собирается из кусочков ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще я бы сказал так: у гугла спрашивали?

[Последовательный выбор с использованием AJAX, jQuery и PHP](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1321).

Comment: скрипт хороший но у меня он не срабатывает к сожалению ...